# Как получить данные из базы данных firebase на Android

Tags: android, firebase

```
package com.example.shop;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;
import androidx.core.view.GravityCompat;
import androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.example.shop.Model.Products;
import com.example.shop.Prevalent.Prevalent;
import com.example.shop.ViewHolder.ProductViewHolder;
import com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter;
import com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerOptions;
import com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton;
import com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView;
import com.google.android.material.snackbar.Snackbar;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

import de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView;
import io.paperdb.Paper;

public class HomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener
{

    private DatabaseReference ProductsRef;
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

        ProductsRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Products");

        Paper.init(this);

        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        toolbar.setTitle("Home");
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FloatingActionButton fab = findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });
        DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

        NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);


        View headerView = navigationView.getHeaderView(0);
        TextView userNameTextView = headerView.findViewById(R.id.profil_name);
        CircleImageView profileImageView = headerView.findViewById(R.id.profile_image);

        userNameTextView.setText(Prevalent.currentOnlineUser.getName());
        Picasso.get().load(Prevalent.currentOnlineUser.getImage()).placeholder(R.drawable.profile).into(profileImageView);

        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.menu);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

    }


    @Override
    protected void onStart()
    {
        super.onStart();

        FirebaseRecyclerOptions<Products> options =
                new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<Products>()
                .setQuery(ProductsRef, Products.class)
                .build();

        FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Products, ProductViewHolder> adapter =
                new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Products, ProductViewHolder>(options)
                {
                    @Override
                    protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ProductViewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull Products model)
                    {
                        holder.txtProductName.setText(model.getPname());
                        holder.txtProductDescription.setText(model.getDescription());
                        holder.txtProductPrice.setText("Price = " + model.getPrice() + "Р");
                        Picasso.get().load(model.getImage()).into(holder.imageView);
                    }

                    @NonNull
                    @Override
                    public ProductViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType)
                    {
                        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.tovar, parent, false);
                        ProductViewHolder holder = new ProductViewHolder(view);
                        return holder;
                    }
                };
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        adapter.startListening();


    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.home, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        int id = item.getItemId();


  //      if (id == R.id.action_settings)
  //      {
  //          return true;
  //      }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.nav_cart)
        {

        }
        else if (id == R.id.nav_orders)
        {

        }
        else if (id == R.id.nav_category)
        {

        }
        else if (id == R.id.nav_settings)
        {
           Intent intent = new Intent(HomeActivity.this, SetingActivity.class);
           startActivity(intent);
        }
        else if (id == R.id.nav_exist)
        {
            Paper.book().destroy();

            Intent intent = new Intent(HomeActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }


        DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
```

Модуль Products

```
package com.example.shop.Model;

public class Products
{
    private String pname, description, price, image, category, pid, date, time;

    public  Products()
    {

    }

    public Products(String pname, String description, String price, String image, String category, String pid, String date, String time) {
        this.pname = pname;
        this.description = description;
        this.price = price;
        this.image = image;
        this.category = category;
        this.pid = pid;
        this.date = date;
        this.time = time;
    }


    public String getPname() {
        return pname;
    }

    public void setPname(String pname) {
        this.pname = pname;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public String getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(String price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    public String getImage() {
        return image;
    }

    public void setImage(String image) {
        this.image = image;
    }

    public String getCategory() {
        return category;
    }

    public void setCategory(String category) {
        this.category = category;
    }

    public String getPid() {
        return pid;
    }

    public void setPid(String pid) {
        this.pid = pid;
    }

    public String getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate(String date) {
        this.date = date;
    }

    public String getTime() {
        return time;
    }

    public void setTime(String time) {
        this.time = time;
    }
}
```

[image: Вот что надо вывести в android]

[image: Вот ЛОг ошибок]

Comment: Вставьте ошибку текстом, т.к. ваша картинка низкого разрешения

Comment: Добавил вроде читаемо

Comment: Я бы рекомендовал изучить как работать с `logcat`, как его читать, и на что обращать внимание. В логах можно найти строку на которой вываливается ошибка. В вашей ошибке самая верхняя строка `Failed to convert value of type java.lang.Long to String` пробовали по ней гуглить? Делать догадки почему это произошло?

Comment: Спасибо буду работать, я гугли ошибку но внятного решения не нашол

Comment: @Вадим У вас ошибка конвертирования данных. проверьте, что вы правильно заполняете класс Products.